# Is it possible to have a persistent psql connection in bash?

Tags: database, bash, postgresql, psql

I have a very large bash script and I make thousands of psql queries throughout it which I suspect is slowing it down. I have created this MWE which proves my theory. I am assuming this slow down is because of having to connect to the db repeatedly. Is there a way to remain connected to psql in bash?

```
#!/bin/bash

 DB_NAME=testdb
 DB_USER=user1  #UPDATE THIS

 #DROP DB
 SQL_QUERY="DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS $DB_NAME;"
 echo $SQL_QUERY | sudo -u $DB_USER psql >/dev/null

 #CREATE DB
 SQL_QUERY="CREATE DATABASE $DB_NAME;"
 echo $SQL_QUERY | sudo -u $DB_USER psql >/dev/null

 #CREATE TABLE
 SQL_QUERY="CREATE TABLE foo
 (
     id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
     problems INTEGER
 );"
 echo $SQL_QUERY | sudo -u $DB_USER psql -d $DB_NAME >/dev/null

 TARGET_ITERATIONS=1000

 #MULTIPLE DB CALLS
 SQL_QUERY="INSERT INTO foo
 (
     problems
 )
 VALUES
 (
     99
 );"

 START_TIME=$(date +%s)
 for ITERATION in $(seq $TARGET_ITERATIONS)
 do
     echo $SQL_QUERY | sudo -u $DB_USER psql -d $DB_NAME >/dev/null
 done
 STOP_TIME=$(date +%s)

 echo "Multiple Call Duration (s): $((STOP_TIME-START_TIME))"

 #Single db call
 SQL_QUERY=""

 for ITERATION in $(seq $TARGET_ITERATIONS)
 do
     SQL_QUERY+="INSERT INTO foo
     (
         problems
     )
     VALUES
     (
         99
     );"

 done

 START_TIME=$(date +%s)
 echo $SQL_QUERY | sudo -u postgres psql -d $DB_NAME >/dev/null
 STOP_TIME=$(date +%s)
 echo "Single Call Duration (s): $((STOP_TIME-START_TIME))"
```

**Output:**

```
$ ./test_psql.sh
Multiple Call Duration (s): 64
Single Call Duration (s): 12
```

Comment: make a unique file instead of a ` echo | connection`   ; make a `connection filename.sql`  I think you will make quite result ; if it is not efficient you might look around the `parallel` command to open as many sql session as you have core for example

Comment: Use `mkfifo /tmp/mypipe` to create a named pipe, make it world-readable with `chmod a+r /tmp/mypipe` .  Run a process like `cat > /tmp/mypipe &` to hold it open.  Connect once to `psql` with `sudo -u $DB_USER psql -f /tmp/mypipe`.  Use `echo $SQL_QUERY > /tmp/mypipe`.  Make sure you send a `\q` when you are done and clean up the `cat` command.  If security is an issue, then you will need to figure out how to use `mktemp` to create a directory in `/tmp` where you can create the fifo.

Comment: You might also look into using a coprocess.

Comment: @MikeOrganek can you provide a MWE as an answer. I can't seem to get your suggestion to work

Answer (score 2):

Per your comment, try running this:

```
#/bin/bash

mkfifo /tmp/mypipe
chmod a+r /tmp/mypipe
sleep 10000 > /tmp/mypipe &
psql -f /tmp/mypipe &
echo "\pset pager off" > /tmp/mypipe
echo "select count(*) from information_schema.columns;" > /tmp/mypipe
echo "select count(*) from information_schema.columns;" > /tmp/mypipe
sleep 3
echo "select count(*) from information_schema.columns;" > /tmp/mypipe
echo "\q" > /tmp/mypipe
rm /tmp/mypipe
```

Comment: Now, how do you get the data back from the queries into bash variables?

Comment: @JayK You read from the named pipe.

Comment: The output of psql is going to stdout, not a named pipe. I've tried a couple of times to make a persistent read/write connection via psql process, but I've never gotten it to work quite right.